# How to handle queuing of "select for update" jobs in a mysql innodb table

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a constant stream of 'select ...for update' queries on an inndob table.

The main condition is that it selects all fields where 'column1' is < than 100.

In the background there are constant inserts going on, which can involve inserts where the 'column1' is < than 100, but this isn't a problem. If the first select for update misses it because it happens whilst that query is being performed, or whilst the results array is being fetched, the next one will catch it and I am happy to mark down the first query as missing it because it was 'too late'.

If I have 10 of these 'select for update' queries waiting, because of the inndob field locking, should I be handling the queuing of them myself or do I let the database sort it out? I presume the correct way to handle this is to queue the queries myself?

So when the script reaches

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ... FOR UDPATE"
```

Beforehand, check the queue array (?), if the queue array is not empty put this script call in the queue array at the end and then check the queue array every few milliseconds until it reaches number 1 in the queue?

Am I thinking along the right lines here... It is important I get this correct now rather than come back to it later

Edit: is there anything I can add to increase the likelihood of a response :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InnoDB should handle the queueing for you.  If there's a transaction in progress with locks on the relevant rows, then a second transaction trying to acquire the same locks with another SELECT FOR UPDATE statement, then that second statement will wait until the first transaction commits.

You can test this out yourself:

1. Open two bash shell windows, and run the mysql client in each window.
2. Run `START TRANSACTION` in each window.
3. Issue a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` in the first window.
4. Then do the same in the second window, with a WHERE clause that should overlap the same rows.
5. In the first window, run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` and observe the transactions and their locks.  You should see the output includes something like the following:

   ```
   LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
   ---TRANSACTION 3B17, ACTIVE 4 sec starting index read
   mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
   LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 1 row lock(s)
   MySQL thread id 2, OS thread handle 0x7ff27ae2d700, query id 28 192.168.56.1 root Sending data
   select * from foo where id < 100 for update
   ------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 4 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
   RECORD LOCKS space id 266 page no 3 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `test`.`foo` trx id 3B17 lock_mode X waiting
   ------------------
   TABLE LOCK table `test`.`foo` trx id 3B17 lock mode IX
   RECORD LOCKS space id 266 page no 3 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `test`.`foo` trx id 3B17 lock_mode X waiting
   ---TRANSACTION 3B16, ACTIVE 70 sec
   2 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 2 row lock(s)
   MySQL thread id 1, OS thread handle 0x7ff27ae6e700, query id 29 192.168.56.1 root
   show engine innodb status
   TABLE LOCK table `test`.`foo` trx id 3B16 lock mode IX
   RECORD LOCKS space id 266 page no 3 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `test`.`foo` trx id 3B16 lock_mode X
   ```

Notice in the above, transaction 3B16 holds locks, and transaction 3B17 is waiting for locks.

Transaction 3B16 shows it's currently running "show engine innodb status" but it still holds the locks it acquired in its previous SELECT ... FOR UPDATE.  Even though that statement is finished, the transaction is not, and locks are released when the transaction finishes.

If transaction 3B17 waits longer than `lock_wait_timeout` seconds, and the first transaction still hasn't committed or rolled back, then the waiting statement gives up and yields this error:

```
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Comment: What would happen if there were e.g. 10 of these queries waiting? Does inndob automatically handle them in the right order?

Comment: Yes. But you don't need to take my word for it, you can test the behavior yourself by doing an experiment similar to what I described above, but open a couple more windows and get more sessions queued up.  Then as you commit each session (not the ones waiting, but the ones that have finished their SELECT) it will let the next one in the queue execute its statement, in the order they entered the queue.